# Compare a string in one array, with a wildcard string in another

Tags: arrays, powershell, compare, wildcard

I have two arrays, `$a` and `$b`, within array `$a` is a string which could partially match one of the entries in `$b`, assuming I could use a wildcard:

```
$a = "1", "Computer Name", "2"
$b = "3", "4", "Full Computer Name Here"

foreach ($line in $a) {
    foreach ($line2 in $b) {
         where "*$line*" -like "*$line2*"
    }
}
```

I've got here after trying all the simple 'this array matches that array', into `foreach` for one array, then tried all the `Select-String` to `Compare-Object $line $line2 -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -PassThru`, but can't get anything to work.

Ideally, it'd return 'Full Computer Name Here' where it matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$b | Where {$_ | Select-String $a}
```

---

Updated 2018-06-23

*Credits for LotsPings' comment to minimize it further to:*

Apparently, `Select-String` has already both iterators in itself and therefore it can be simplified to just:

### `$b | Select-String $a`

```
PS C:\> $a = "1", "Computer Name", "Other Name"
PS C:\> $b = "Computer", "4", "Full Computer Name Here", "something else", "Also full computer name here"
PS C:\> $b | Select-String $a

Full Computer Name Here
Also full computer name here
```

Comment: That isn't very different from `$b | Select-String $a` (aside from some blank lines) but the RegEx restrictions mentioned by @AnsgarWiechers apply also (+1)

Comment: @LotPings, you completely right, my answer was evolving yesterday when I was writing it but didn't go to the bottom as I needed to leave in a hurry. I have aggravated the input arrays to prove the result is correct and changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: You may want to add the parameter `-SimpleMatch`, otherwise your code might produce incorrect matches with input containing special characters ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)).

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?

```
$a = "1","Computer Name","2"
$b = "3","4","Full Computer Name Here"
foreach ($line in $a ) {
    $b -match $line
}
```

**EDIT:**
Probably not the best answer despite it's simplicity as illustrated by @Ansgar in the comments. Sometimes PowerShell is so inconsistent it makes me wonder why I still use it.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that comparison operators implicitly work as enumerators too. Note, however, that the `-match` operator does a regular expression match, which might yield undesired results if a comparison string contains special characters.

Comment: Yes indeed. I knew I was missing something about `-match` not being the best option. But since all array elements are string, I think it will survive this one.

Comment: `$a = "foo."; $b = "foo.example.org", "foobar.example.org"`

Comment: Hmm? The behavior is perfectly consistent. The `-match` operator does regular expression matches, so the match string is handled as a regular expression. It's not a bad thing, just something you need to be aware of when using match strings from some other source. Escape the string and everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

`Where-Object` doesn't work that way. It reads from a pipeline that you don't have in your code. Also, your comparison is backwards, and you must not add wildcard characters to the reference value.

Change your code to something like this:

```
foreach ($line in $a) {
    $b | Where-Object { $_ -like "*${line}*" }
}
```

or like this:

```
foreach ($line in $a) {
    foreach ($line2 in $b) {
        if ($line2 -like "*${line}*") { $line2 }
    }
}
```

and it will do what you expect.

**Edit:**

I keep forgetting that comparison operators also work as enumerators, so the latter example could be simplified to something like this (removing the nested loop and conditional):

```
foreach ($line in $a) {
    $b -like "*${line}*"
}
```